# Java Drools - How to fire two rules?

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rule-engine

I'm new to drools and trying to fire two rules for my requirement.

Rules: Only one from the below, the first one W rule is firing, how to fire the second rule as well?

```
W rule:

rule "Send an incoming request to W" salience 1
when
    There is an incoming message
    Not routed yet
then
   Create W Request for Cash
   Route to "WQueue".

F Rule:

rule "Send an incoming request to F"
when
    There is an incoming message
    Not routed yet or Routed to "WQueue"
then
   Create F Request for Cash
   Route to "FQueue".
```

Consequnce and condition:

For the 2nd rule `F Rule` I am using the `1st` and `3rd` conditions from below in the `when`

```
[*][]Not routed yet=$out : Router(hasNotRoutes == true)
[consequence][]Route to {routeNames}\.=modify($out) \{addRoute({routeNames})\};
[*][]Routed to {routeName}=$out : Router(routes contains {routeName})
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a *single* condition `Not routed or routed to {routeName}` ... something like this:

```
[*][]Not routed or routed to {routeName}=$out : Router(hasNotRoutes == true || routes contains {routeName})
```

Right now you're or-ing `$out : Router(hasNotRoutes == true)` and `$out : Router(routes contains {routeName})` which doesn't work for a variety of syntax-related reasons (the `$out` assignment is part of both, for example).